# How to layout scrolling ListBox with auto max height and attach always visible Button below?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want a layout where a ListBox is placed at the top of the window and a button is attached to the bottom of the ListBox. When the window is too small I want the ListBox to scroll and the button to be visible. When the window is too large, i.e. enough space for all controls and all list items, I want the ListBox to take up exactly as much space as it needs, and empty space be added below the button.

I have tried DockPanel:

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="525">
        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
            <ListBox Name="List" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                <ListBoxItem>Item</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Item</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Item</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Item</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Item</ListBoxItem>
                <ListBoxItem>Item</ListBoxItem>
            </ListBox>
            <Button Content="Button" DockPanel.Dock="Top"></Button>
        </DockPanel>
    </Window>
```

But then the button is not visible when the window is too small.

I have tried Grid:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Name="List" Grid.Row="0">
            <ListBoxItem>Item</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>Item</ListBoxItem>            
        </ListBox>
        <Button Content="Button" Grid.Row="1"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But when the window is larger than needed, the ListBox is stretched larger than its content instead of empty space being added below the button.

If I change the RowDefinitions to:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Then the Listbox does not scroll when the window is too small.

Any ideas?

Comment: what about your variant #2 (`<RowDefinition Height="*"/> <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>`) *and* `<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">`? (it works with this example, but may be not so good in more complex layout)

Comment: @ASh Thanks! That works perfectly! You should write it as an answer. As for more complex layout, I guess that would have to be another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change Grid.VerticalAlignment. If it is set to Stretch (default value) and the window is larger than needed, the ListBox is also stretched because of `Height="*"`.

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```